# Which is the most optimal way to get or set the value of a property using reflection

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, reflection

What is the most optimal way to repeatedly get or set the value of a property using reflection in a long-term perspective?

I tried using plain old reflection but this solution seems a little bit slow to me. I need another solution.

Comment: The best way is to not use reflection at all, you have a plethora of other tools at your disposal.

Comment: What is "plain old reflection", and what is "a little bit slow", and perhaps most importantly, in what context do you find yourself needing reflection -- is it actually a bottleneck, and is there any chance your particular use case has already been covered by existing libraries that already have had a lot of optimization effort go into them? Be sure to read [Eric Lippert's evergreen rant on performance questions](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) as well.

Comment: Well, sometimes it is necessary if one wants to automate a given process. For example, I use reflection in some of my libraries to reduce the amount of code that is required to make things work. You can check out [TryAtSoftware.Randomizer](https://github.com/TryAtSoftware/Randomizer) and [TryAtSoftware.Equalizer](https://github.com/TryAtSoftware/Equalizer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct! Reflection (in its natural form) is not a performant solution. However, I can suggest using pre-compiled expressions because they are way more efficient and by using them you can benefit from type safety. You can read more about the idea in this [article](https://medium.com/@tonyslav_troeff/optimize-reflection-calls-in-net-408fe3df868f) on Medium.

You can also check out a library that I contribute to - `TryAtSoftware.Extensions.Reflection`. It exposes extension methods that can help construct appropriate expressions. It is [open-source](https://github.com/TryAtSoftware/Extensions) and available as a NuGet package.

Comment: It would be generally considered good form to mention that you are the (primary) author of a library, if you're recommending it in an answer, as you appear to be; in fact this is [policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). This is true even if you're not (directly) making money from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can cache a delegate to the property's getter/setter.

For example

```
private Func<SomeClass, string> _unknownPropertyGetter;

void SetProperty(string propertyName)
{
    _unknownPropertyGetter =
        typeof(SomeClass)
          .GetProperty(propertyName)
          .GetMethod
          .CreateDelegate<Func<SomeClass, string>>();
     // note that it's an open instance delegate
}

string GetMyProperty(SomeClass obj)
{
    return _unknownPropertyGetter(obj);
}
```

You could cache it any way you like, for example in a dictionary.